# Pylint not-an-iterable on a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint

I am getting this warning:

> Non-iterable value ls is used in an iterating context Pylint(E1133:not-an-iterable)

From:

```
def find(ls: list[str], value: str, ignore_case: bool = False) -> bool:
    """
    Find method for search an element in a list.
    """
    if ignore_case:
        for s in ls:
            if s.lower() == value.lower():
                return True
        
        return False

    for s in ls:
        if s == value:
            return True
    
    return False
```

Details:

> Python 3.9.13

Why?

Comment: What line is your warning appearing on?

Comment: Hm, I can not reproduce. Which version do you use?

Comment: I just added the Python full version. It is appearing on the ls vars.

Comment: @jnbdz You should also include the version of Pylint you're using.

Comment: I am importing: `from typing import overload`

Comment: You might try changing `ls: list` to `ls: list[str]` and see if that does the trick.

Comment: @jnbdz Hm. That isn't in your presented code - why are you using `overload`?

Comment: @rhurwitz Minor modification: `ls: List[str]`, and you'll need to import `List`.

Comment: Actually `List` is deprecated as of Python 3.9 and the built-in `list` keyword is the preferred type hint:
[Deprecated since version 3.9: builtins.list now supports []. See PEP 585 and Generic Alias Type.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.List)

Comment: @rhurwitz Oh, nice! I hadn't realized that. Thanks!

Comment: @rhurwitz I changed it to `list[str]`. I tried `List[str]` but I cannot find it in `pip3`.

Comment: I did not see the previous comment about `List` being deprecated. I changed it back to `list[str]`.

Comment: How do I get the version of **PyLint**? I am using the one in VS code.